# Date formats in PMPRO wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a custom addon for paid membership pro wordpress plugin. In this plugin, every user level is an object, so they have start date and finish date. But my question does not specially concerns this plugin, but the format of its dates. 
When i try to print the start date or finish date of a level in this plugin, i get it like this :

```
1517586401
```

But i cant understand what a date format is this. How can i convert this to normal date like `yyyy/mm/dd` ? 
This is the complete level object :

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [ID] => 3 
    [id] => 3 
    [subscription_id] => 20 
    [name] => level3
    [description] => test description 
    [expiration_number] => 1 
    [expiration_period] => Month 
    [allow_signups] => 1 
    [initial_payment] => 45000.00 
    [billing_amount] => 40000.00 
    [cycle_number] => 1 
    [cycle_period] => Month 
    [billing_limit] => 0 
    [trial_amount] => 0.00 
    [trial_limit] => 0 
    [code_id] => 0 
    [startdate] => 1517586401 
    [enddate] => 1519936200 
    [categories] => Array () 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is UNIX epoch time. You can convert using the PHP built in class DateTime:

```
$epoch = 1517586401;
$date = new DateTime("@$epoch");
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
```

For the object, you could do this:

```
$start_date_epoch = object->startdate;
$end_date_epoch = object->enddate;

$start_date = new DateTime("@$start_date_epoch");
$end_date = new DateTime("@$end_date_epoch");

echo $start_date->format('Y/m/d');
echo $end_date->formate('Y/m/d');
```

You can also use `gmdate()`

```
echo gmdate('Y/m/d', $start_date_epoch);
echo gmdate('Y/m/d', $end_date_epoch);
```